# Getting unauthorized when trying to connect to server side

Tags: python, express

I have a server side in `express` `(nodejs)` and I have `ntlm` authentication. 
I want to send an `Http` request from a `python` script to my server.
However, when im sending an http request to the server I get a response of `HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized`.
I tried using the module requests and send an authentication header like this: `requests.get('https://myWebsite.com/something', auth=('myuser', 'mypass'))` however it doesnt work, it still gives the same error back.

I dont want to remove my authentication, but I dont know how to fix this.

Comment: when the server says 401 something with the authentication is wrong. Wrong credentials, wrong encryption, wrong authentication type (server-side expects other as client sends). without further details i guess nobody can help you because it's too vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have to use [requests-ntlm](https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm), to enable support for NTLM inside requests.

After a `pip install requests_ntlm`, you can do (I'm reporting the official examples here):

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

requests.get("http://ntlm_protected_site.com",auth=HttpNtlmAuth('domain\\username','password'))
```

Use a `Session` object to enable NTLM auth across an entire session:

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

session = requests.Session()
session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth('domain\\username','password')
session.get('http://ntlm_protected_site.com')
```